# How to use the geotiffinfo command in Matlab (Mac Version)?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use this:

```
mapinfo = geotiffinfo('a.tif');

Undefined function or variable 'geotiffinfo'.
```

This command works on Matlab Windows version. Both are 2015 versions.

Comment: This function requires the [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/index.html). Are you sure you have that installed? If you do, you should see it listed when you type in `ver`.

Comment: Thanks. Nope, I don't have it installed.

Comment: You can also do `which geotiffinfo` and see what MATLAB gives you.  if it says no function is found, then you certainly don't have the Mapping Toolbox.